# R package development - How to handle C library linking errors on package install

Tags: r, c, package, devtools

## Situation:

The R package I am developing exports a C function through R's `.C`.

The code in `src/` where the function is defined compiles fine if libtiff is installed in the OS.

I'd like this functionality to be optional; just as there are "suggested" R packages, because it is not essential.

## The problem

I found no way to tell R that a C function compilation is "suggested". Neither could I find a way to make compilation of code in src/ optional, or conditional to the presence of libtiff in the OS in some way.

My current Makevars says:

```
CC=ccache clang -Qunused-arguments
CXX=ccache clang++ -Qunused-arguments
CCACHE_CPP2=yes    
PKG_LIBS = -ltiff
```

I have been searching for a solution all day, without success.

I've only just figured out how to use Makevars to look for libtiff:

```
TIFFSTATUS := $(shell $(LD) -ltiff; echo 0 || echo 1)
ifeq ($(TIFFSTATUS), 1)
... stuff?
```

## The question

How can I properly tell R that a function using `.C` is optional (ie conditional to the availability of the libtiff dependencies).

Thanks.

Comment: In the meantime, i have managed to include the libtiff source and compiling it on package install, as suggested [here](http://www.simplesystems.org/libtiff/build.html) with `cmake`, then extracting the source to `src/tiff410` and [telling Makevars](https://github.com/gerbeldo/rcell2/commit/bce626286c40425664ab9c578066dda3a10997da) about it.